# How do I change the state of a parent Component through several layers of child components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Problem Summary:**

I have a parent component that has a state. I need this state changed **from** component d.

The problem is this the child of a child of a child component, as pictured below:

[image: Component Tree]

I just need an example of the state changing from true to false and vice versa.

**What I tried:**

- Tried passing props, but props are immutable
- Tried creating a function that does this and passing that function as a prop, but when I call it from component D it says I can't pass an argument.
- My closest try was passing the function that sets the state from parent to child, but it never actually sets anything:

```
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
    
  const [isLame, setIsLame] = useState(false);
        
  return (
    <div className="React">
        <h1>React is lame</h1>
          <ChildComponentB setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have another part of the application where this works, but because I have so many nested children, I can't pass them through all the children. For example:

Child Component B contains child component C:

```
        
... 
  return (
    <div className="React">
        <h1>React is lame</h1>
          <childComponentC setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

... and Child Component C contains child component D:

```
export default function childComponentC() {
        
... 
  return (
    <div className="React">
        <h1>React is lame</h1>
          <childComponentD setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

...And child component D contains the condition where I need the change the state in the parent component:

```
export default function childComponentD() {
        
... 

   //Tell the parent react is lame
   setIsLame(true);

  return (
    <div className="React">
        <h1>React is lame</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...Does anyone have an example of something like this working?

**Follow up stuff based on comments / responses:**

- I can't use some external tool like redux
- The error I'm getting is that setIsLame(true) is not a function.

Comment: `when I call it from component D it says I can't pass an argument.` Can you be more specific about what error you're seeing?

Comment: Passing the `setIsLame` function should work fine, maybe you could share a complete minimal example of the problem you are seeing?

Comment: @NicholasTower Added response to end of post because comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: `setIsLame(true) is not a function` Ok, the code you showed in your question says `function childComponentD()` with no props. That matches with the error. Is that the way it is in the original code? Or do you have a prop, as in `function childComponentD({ setIsLame })`?

Comment: I ask because: passing a function down as a prop is the right way to do this. But the code you showed looks like it's a long way off from using props, so i'm not sure what advice to provide.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some state management like *TanStack Query* this is a powerful asynchronous state management for react or use *redux* this tow  tools are the most famous tools used with react

you can find some vid on youtube explaning that tools

Answer (score 0):

The error "`setIsLame` is not a function" occurs because the initial `setIsLame` function in the root `App` component is passed down as `stateChanger` for some reason. Then each component from there appears to pass along an undefined `setIsLame` variable/reference to yet another `stateChanger` prop. I don't see ***any*** of the components consuming any React props either, so even if they passed `stateChanger={stateChanger}` as a prop it'd still be undefined.

Each component must actually consume the props they desire to pass down.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLame, setIsLame] = useState(false);
        
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentB setIsLame={setIsLame} /> // <-- setIsLame prop passed
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentB({ setIsLame }) { // <-- setIsLame prop consumed
  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentC setIsLame={setIsLame} /> // <-- setIsLame prop passed
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentC({ setIsLame }) { // <-- setIsLame prop consumed
  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentD setIsLame={setIsLame} /> // <-- setIsLame prop passed
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentD({ setIsLame }) { // <-- setIsLame prop consumed
  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={setIsLame}> // <-- setIsLame prop used
        Announce that React is lame
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

```js
function ChildComponentD({ setIsLame }) {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component D - React is lame</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsLame(isLame => !isLame)}>
        Announce that React is lame
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponentC({ setIsLame }) {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component C - React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentD setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponentB({ setIsLame }) {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component B - React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentC setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [isLame, setIsLame] = React.useState(false);
        
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame: {JSON.stringify(isLame)}</h1>
      <ChildComponentB setIsLame={setIsLame} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
.React {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

.React > h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

This resolves the issue of passing the correct prop value down through all that apps... but this is a complete anti-pattern as now all components between `App` and `ChildComponentD` ***necessarily*** need to be aware of this `setIsLame` prop and pass it down ***even though*** they don't care about or us it.

This problem known as ***"Props Drilling"***.

To address this problem you should introduce a [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) to the app so that `App` can provide the `setIsLame` function to its sub-ReactTree and ***only*** the descendent components that care about it explicitly access the provided context value.

Example Implementation:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export const ReactIsLameContext = createContext({
  setIsLame: () => {}
});

export const useReactIsLame = () => useContext(ReactIsLameContext);

const ReactIsLameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLame, setIsLame] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ReactIsLameContext.Provider value={{ setIsLame }}>
      {children}
    </ReactIsLameContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ReactIsLameProvider;
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ReactIsLameProvider>
        <ChildComponentB /> // <-- no props passed
      </ReactIsLameProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentB() { // <-- no props consumed
  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentC /> // <-- no props passed
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentC() { // <-- no props consumed
  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentD /> // <-- no props passed
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ChildComponentD() { // <-- no props consumed
  const { setIsLame } = useReactIsLame(); // <-- access setIsLame from context

  ... 

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={setIsLame}>
        Announce that React is lame
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

```js
const ReactIsLameContext = React.createContext({
  isLame: false,
  setIsLame: () => {}
});

const useReactIsLame = () => React.useContext(ReactIsLameContext);

const ReactIsLameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLame, setIsLame] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ReactIsLameContext.Provider value={{ isLame, setIsLame }}>
      {children}
    </ReactIsLameContext.Provider>
  );
};

function ChildComponentD() {
  const { setIsLame } = useReactIsLame();

  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component D - React is lame</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsLame(isLame => !isLame)}>
        Announce that React is lame
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponentC() {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component C - React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentD />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponentB() {
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>Component B - React is lame</h1>
      <ChildComponentC />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const { isLame } = useReactIsLame();
  
  return (
    <div className="React">
      <h1>React is lame: {JSON.stringify(isLame)}</h1>
      <ChildComponentB />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ReactIsLameProvider>
      <App />
    </ReactIsLameProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
.React {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

.React > h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: @DaveCat What is `setIsCountingDown`? If it's a function like `setIsLame` then it should also be pissed down in the same way. I can provide a live demo if you like.

Comment: It keeps saying setIsLame is not a function. I want to pass it as a function with an argument. I've also tried making it into a function in the parent component that contains an argument, but it doesn't let me pass it as a prop. It just says the argument isn't defined when I try to pass it in while instantiating componentB.

Comment: @DaveCat You seem to be changing the scope of your issue/problem now. I believe my answer stands as-is against the information, i.e. the code, you have provided in your post. If *that* code isn't an accurate representation of your problem and what you are actually trying to do then please do edit it to be a more complete and accurate [mcve].

Comment: No, you're incorrect. The code sample I posted is completely accurate to the problem i'm trying to solve. Your solution just doesn't work. Just exactly like I put in my code sample, setIsLame(false) exists in component D. That is saying it's not a function. Your solution has an onClick that doesn't even pass a parameter.

Comment: @DaveCat Adding/passing the function to an `onClick` handler is *just* an example of the function being defined and used in a descendent component. It's up to you to use the function correctly. I updated my answer to include working code snippets for both solutions I suggest. Please do check them out.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: @DaveCat What are you doing differently in the code on your end? I just provided two working demos. Can you create a ***running*** stack snippet (*the 
 `<>` button*) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the error you are seeing that we could inspect live?